# News API with user location

Tags: feed, userlocation, newsapi

I'm trying to implement an external news feed. I'm currently using Newsapi.org and able to filter news by country and category. But I would like the news to be local to each user. Is there a way to  get the users's location and some how use it in the API to filter local news? If this can be done with Newsapi.org, great!, but I'm willing to use a different API if I need to. Thanks!

I'm currently using Newsapi.org and able to filter news by country and category. But I would like the news to be local to each user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would help you but you could get user's current location [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) and filter only news from user's country and language. Of course this is not accurate as the news could still be about global matters. But it's a start.